# How can I overlay images (png) within a website?

Tags: html, png, overlay

I am trying to mount an image in the middle of another (slightly larger) image so that it appears to be within the larger image (a phone in this case). I am unsure of the proper way to make this happen and any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the `z-index` css property.

HTML:

```
<img id="png1" src="png1.png" />
<img id="png2" src="png2.png" />
```

CSS:

```css
#png1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}

#png2 {
    position:absolute;
    /*
    set top and left here
    */
    z-index:1;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/6VSBv/

Comment: Ah! Thank you oh so much, very straight forward! Stay awesome!

Comment: Another quick question, sorry about my ignorance o.O, but if the positioning of png1 is centered via html, as in not in the top left as it was in the provided example, how do I set the positioning of png2 to be relative to it (I think that makes sense, if not let me know!) Thank you oh so much!

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out all on my lonesome, thank you so much again! And I check'd it! Best wishes!

Answer (score -1):

```
<img style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;" src="img1.png">
<img style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:20px;" src="img2.png">
```

Of course, you will need to adjust the coordinates, and I would highly recommend putting the CSS in a stylesheet instead of inline. Here's a pretty good tutorial on CSS for more information: http://www.csstutorial.net/

Answer (score -1):

So you are new to html and CSS. That's no problem, but your question is a little bit vague for [SO's general format](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

However, in a nutshell:

```
<style>
    #phone {background: url('http://www.knowabouthealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/iphone.jpg') center no-repeat; width: 300px; height: 392px; border: 1px solid #000000;}
    #display {background: #000000; margin: 80px auto 0px; width: 164px; height: 246px; color: #FFFFFF;}
</style>
<div id="phone">
    <div id="display">
        Hello! What is up? Miley rocks!
    </div>
</div>
```

**Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/cbn4L/**

This of course is a extremely simple example. And as you can see the inner container is not a image, but text.. Technically you can add there a image now.. but as we are easing you in to the world of HTML & CSS, then this is a better example and maybe can enhance your concept :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question at all. You aren't overlaying any PNG's here.

Comment: @Matt Anderson: Well, OP is obviously a beginner.. so if the outer image is a phone, then my example is probably something similar to his higher goal. So technically, this a more of a teaching and alternative answer -- trying to understand what OP really wants to do.